# python interpreter command inputs

Tags: python, interpreter

Today by accident I found pressing <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> in a python interpreter lists the contents of the directory the interpreter was started from. Stranger still is that the sequence needs to be performed twice for it to work initially but afterwards works every time.

I couldn't find this feature documented anywhere and I am wondering if there are other undocumented features of the interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a feature of the terminal, not the interpreter. <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> is interpreted as <kbd>Tab</kbd> by your terminal, which your interpreter then further interprets as a completion request.